# o erro "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type" qndo já defini a operação como number

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estou usando o angular pela primeira vez e fazendo uma lista de cursos e eles tem pontuações, e estou tentando colocar estrelas de acordo com suas pontuações.
Pra isso, criei  com o component.
No html está dando esse erro do título, mas eu especifiquei o rating como number. Ainda tem um segundo erro dizendo que a propriedade rating não existe, mas existe. rs *"Property 'rating' does not exist on type 'CourseListComponent'"*

Segue o código HTML

```html
   <h2>Course List</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>Options</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let course of courses">
      <td>{{ course.imageUrl }}</td>
      <td>{{ course.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ course.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ course.code }}</td>
      <td>
        <app-star [rating]="course - rating"></app-star>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Agora, o código typescript

```js
    import { identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler';

export class Course {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  price: number;
  code: string;
  duration: number;
  rating: number;

  constructor(
    id: number,
    name: string,
    imageUrl: '',
    price: number,
    code: string,
    duration: number,
    rating: number
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.price = price;
    this.code = code;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.rating = rating;
  }
}
```

A classe course é instanciada em

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from './course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: Course[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courses = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'angular-forms',
        imageUrl: '',
        price: 99.99,
        code: 'XPS-8967',
        duration: 120,
        rating: 4.6,
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'java-iniciante',
        imageUrl: '',
        price: 99.99,
        code: 'XPS-7799',
        duration: 120,
        rating: 4.0,
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

eu criei esse componente app-star pra tentar colocar as estrelas de acordo com a classificação, o código ficou assim

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-star',
  templateUrl: './star.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./star.component.css'],
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  rating: number = 0;

  starWidth!: number;

  constructor() {
    this.starWidth = this.starWidth;
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.starWidth = (this.rating * 94) / 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nossa, confuso demais isso aí, pq está inicializando as propriedades no construtor? Está instanciando essa classe onde? O que seria isto `<app-star [rating]="course - rating"></app-star>`???

Comment: Ei lê, to inicializando elas no construtor porque antes dava o seguinte erro pra cada uma delas "Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.". vou colocar onde estou instanciando a classe no post. Esse app-star é uma tag que eu criei com o angular pra colocar estrelas de acordo com a classificação.

Comment: Ainda está confuso, mas, pelo que vi a classe **Course** poderia ser uma `interface` ou uma `classe abstrata (melhor pq dá para ser instanciada)`, para não ter que ficar definindo valores nela, apenas sendo um modelo. Dito isto, não vi relação com o erro da pergunta e o código apresentado na mesma, a única coisa que me vem a cabeça é o problema estar em `[rating]="course - rating"` qual tipo de dado que esse **`[rating]`** aceita?

Comment: o rating aceita a classificação dos cursos, ou seja, números. percebi que não tinha mostrado essa parte do código e adicionei a pergunta, veja lá. tentei tornar a classe abstrata e continuou dando o mesmo erro de antes! ):

Comment: Então minha querida, se aceita números, pq, está passando **string**??

Answer (score -2):

Na classe **Course** a propriedade **RATING** é do tipo **NUMBER** e você está passando um tipo **STRING**, por isso não consegue instanciá-la no component.

```
class Course {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  price: number;
  code: string;
  duration: number;
  rating: number;
}
```

**[rating]="course - rating"**

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Tente [rating]="couses.rating" . Assim o rating vai receber o valor do atributo da lista de courses.